# Twilio - Authentication Error - No credentials provided SDK C#

Tags: c#, api, sdk, sms, twilio

After some tests my sample stoped to work

I'm using :

```
PM> Install-Package Twilio

Attempting to resolve dependency 'RestSharp (≥ 105.2.2)'.
'Twilio 4.7.2' already installed.
Adding 'RestSharp 105.2.2' to HelperSMS.
Successfully added 'RestSharp 105.2.2' to HelperSMS.
Adding 'Twilio 4.7.2' to HelperSMS.
Successfully added 'Twilio 4.7.2' to HelperSMS.
```

and the error is:

> ((Twilio.TwilioBase)(message)).RestException.Code = 20003
>
> ((Twilio.TwilioBase)(message)).RestException.Message = "Authentication
>   Error - No credentials provided"
>
> ((Twilio.TwilioBase)(message)).RestException.Status = 401

Here my code :

```html
// Download the twilio-csharp library from twilio.com/docs/csharp/install
using System;
using Twilio;
class Example
{
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
    // Find your Account Sid and Auth Token at twilio.com/user/account
    string AccountSid = "..............";
    string AuthToken = "..............";
    var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);

    var message = twilio.SendMessage(
        "+15017250604", "+15558675309",
        "This is the ship that made the Kessel Run in fourteen parsecs?",
        new string[] { "https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2899/14341091933_1e92e62d12_b.jpg" }
    );
    Console.WriteLine(message.Sid);
 }
}
```

> Edited
>
> I've tried today to make this call from my personal network (all other
>   tests was made inside the network of my company). It's like something
>   strange in our network. Firewall, Bluecoat, Proxy?? some idea?

Comment: So did it work from your personal network? How are you setting the `AccountSid` and `AuthToken` in that file?

Comment: I found the bug, actually, our bluecote replaces the API Key to something other, so Twilio did not know the API Key.

Comment: Glad to hear it's solved!